# Integral of $z$ over a triangle doesnt't match the result from Cauchy-Goursat theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given a triangle with vertices $0,1,i$ I'm asked to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\partial \triangle} \! z \ dz$$ by the Cauchy-Goursat theorem I know that the integral is equal to zero because $f(z)=z$ is an entire function; however when I calulte the integral without the theorem I end up with this result that makes no sense: $$\int_{\partial \triangle} \! z \ dz = \int_0^1 \! t \ dt + \int_1^i \! (i-1) \left(it+1-t \right) \ dt + \int_i^0 \! -i\ i(1-t)\ dt = -i$$.

I used the parametrization of the paths joining the vertices of the triangle, so I know that there is an error but I don't see where.

Comment: Do it by definition, without shortcuts. What do you mean by an integral from $1$ to $i$, and how did you get that integrand? A parametrization has to be a path $[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ where $a<b$ are real.

Comment: @user170231 No, if $t=0$ you have $\textbf i$ that is not correct

Comment: You need to change integration limits to $0$ and $1$ in every integral, because when you parametrize the curves your new integration variable is $t$

Answer (score 1):

Second integral should go from $0$ to $i$, as $y=t$. Also I think you messed up on the third integral. These are the parametrizations I used:

For path $0\to1$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&x=t\\
&y=0
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies z(t)=t\ \text{ for } t\in(0,1)\implies \text dz=\text dt
$$

For path $1\to i$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&x=t\\
&y=1-t
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies z(t)=t+i(1-t)=(1-i)t+i\ \text{ for } t\in(1,0)\implies \text dz=(1-i)dt
$$
For path $i\to0$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&x=0\\
&y=t
\end{aligned}
\right\}\implies z(t)=it\ \text{ for } t\in(1,0)\implies \text dz=i\text dt
$$
Finally, we can now compute the integral
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\partial\triangle}zdz&=\int_0^1 t\text dt+\int_1^0[(1-i)t+i](1-i)\text dt+\int_1^0iti\text dt\\
&=\int_0^1 t\text dt-\int_1^0t\text dt+\int_1^0[(1-i)^2t+(1+i)]\text dt\\
&=2\left.\frac{t^2}{2}\right|_0^1+\left[(1-i)^2\frac{t^2}{2}+(1+i)t\right|_1^0\\
&=1-(1-i)^2\frac{1}{2}-(1+i)=-\frac{1}{2}(1-2i-1)-i=i-i=0\ \square,
\end{aligned}
$$
which concurs with your initial reasoning.